# Public vs Private

Tags: java, private, public

Following are Java code I did as a practice for a class. I have a class named SavingsAccount. It has balance and interest variables. However, I set them to public, but if I want to treat the accounts individually, do I need to make them private and have "get/set" methods for those variables? Can I not just get away with it having the variables public? The rest of the codes have methods that calculate using those variables.

```
public class SavingsAccount { //This class has three different variables that define it
    public double balance; //Double for account balance
    public static double annualInterestRate; //Class method for interest rate
    public final int ACCOUNT_NUMBER; //Constant int for keeping track of accounts


public SavingsAccount (int ACCOUNT_NUMBER, double balance) { //Constructor that takes down account number and balance to keep track of
        this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
```

Comment: "Treating accounts individually" isn't related to how account data is accessed.

Comment: Can I ask why this was down-voted? I'm trying to learn more about encapsulation.

Comment: I put up a sample code verify with an example. That post didn't have an example. But ok.

Comment: -1 (I wasn't the first to down-vote, but I will justify my vote) You seem to be confusing access modifiers with object encapsulation. Access modifiers are used to restrict access to code from other code. Object encapsulation is about storing data within the bounds of a class instance, usually using static vs. instance members.

Comment: @JesseWebb "Encapsulation" is used to describe two different things: access restriction, and data/behavior bundling. (E.g., see Wikipedia entry.) IMO a downvote instead of discussion is a pretty blunt instrument. Downvotes for a terminology disagreement, particularly when it's a perfectly valid use of the word, is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I set them to public, but if I want to treat the accounts
>   individually, do I need to make them private and have "get/set"
>   methods for those variables?

Firstly, each instance of your class is treated as a seperate SavingAccount.

```
SavingAccount acct1 = new SavingAccount(....); //represents one Saveing account
SavingAccount acct2 = new SavingAccount(....); //represents another Saveing account
```

Doesn't really matter if your attributes are marked public  or private. usually if you wanna encapsulate your class you make your attributes private and have public getter/setter methods so that other objects can't access your attribute directly. they will only be able to access them thru getter/setters.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly *can* have the variables as public but there are plenty of people here who would hunt you down for that...
This is a question of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in the OO paradigm. Generally objects should not be able to poke at the innards of each other.

Comment: make members as private as possible and as public as needed.

Comment: +1, that's your century.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to make fields private for **Data Encapsulation**.  Data Encapsulation is the practice of limiting and controlling access to fields to prevent undesirable actions by programmers.  If you don't do it, a programmer might access or change a variable on an instance in an uncontrolled way which could break things.  In other words, controlling access to variables makes it harder to break things and introduce bugs.

Basically, your classes should work like a "black box".  From the outside, another programmer can't see, and doesn't care, how the internals (i.e. the private fields) work.  You can only interface with the box by using explicitly declared operations (i.e. the public methods).  Those operations will manipulate the internals as necessary.

Of course, you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the variables public, they are directly accessible/settable.
If you define them private, you need getters and setters.

Controlling the access is desirable, declare them private.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to make it private. Let say I am accessing your class and setting the values like below.

SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount(12345,25000);

now I can set my balance using the object directly as follows below:

sa.balance = -300;

sa.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 6789;

There is no security provided in your class.  This is the important concept in OOP called data encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you perform some kind of validation when setting the values (i.e. balance is not negative), use `public` if possible.

Creating both a getter and a setter for an attribute that merely return or assign a value, without additional logic actually exposes your attribute as `public` and provide unnecessary clutter to the code (in terms of readability). Using public attributes directly makes the code cleaner.

**Example 1:**

*You want to allow an account to only have positive balance. You will have to perform a check to see if you are assigning it a negative value EVERY time you assign it a value.

The best place to do this would be in a setter method. This gets you rid of the trouble of having to put a lot of `if(newBalance < 0)` checks all over the place.

To enforce the fact that you want only positive balance values, you make the attribute `private`. This restricts the programmers who might want to assign a negative value to a `balance` attribute(*). In order to make the value held within the balance attribute accessible again, you would need to add a getter for the private value.

You now have "some kind" of a `public` attribute on which you enforce restrictions (not being able to be set as negative).

**Example 2:**

You want to take notes on every account. You will have a `String notes;` attribute in your class.

If there are not restrictions you want to enforce, the best here is to use `public` modifier for it.

Consider which of the following pieces of code is cleaner:

```
accountA.setNotes(accountB.getNotes());
```

or

```
accountA.notes = accountB.notes;
```

They both copy `notes` from one account to the other, but the latter is easier to read.

Comment: your fields should never be public unless absolutely necessary

Comment: agreed - this goes against the concept of OO.

Comment: -1 - The idea using of accessors and mutators is to allow you to change the implementation later without needing to update a bunch of other code. For instance, I could change a simple setter to include validation. Or I could change a getter to not return the private field anymore and instead perform a calculation. I would say the "clutter" is worth it, especially since most IDEs will generate this code for you anyway.

Comment: to avoid 'clutter' check out [project lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: @JesseWebb Yes, that is another use for getters and setters, I agree with you, but looking at the class written in the question this has the purpose of holding data. For a better explanation of what I'm trying to explain there is a good chapter on Data/Object Anti-Symmetry in Clean Code by Robin C. Martin. http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: Agree with lucian partially. It is OK to make fields public when you are dealing with data transfer objects, but only if they are immutable. When they are immutable, you can do all the checks in the constructor; fields can be safely opened public. Behavior classes, OTOH, should really have all their fields as private as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to set some fields `private` instead of `public`.
Because, using proper methods to access them provides neat code and less bugs.

Just think of yourself, someone wants to know your account number to give you a gift in the way of cash.
What will you prefer either The person asking you promptly and getting your A/c. No or You publicly announce your A/c No. and the person gets himself the A/c No. without informing you.
The first seems to make it `private` and use `get`/`set` methods.
The second seems to make it `public`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible to point out two distinct cases where you want and where you do not want to use public fields.

First one is when you are using immutable data structures. I'm totally convinced that immutable data structures is something you want to strive to. Pros and cons of immutable structures can be found elsewhere; in regard to public fields immutable structures suggest the obvious thing - make all fields public. Well, structure is immutable, so you can only read values. In this case getters are totally unnecessary and only clutter your code.

And second one, obviously, is when you are using mutable structures. In this case usage of getters and setters is justified; it is wholly possible that you will put some logic in setters, and encapsulating data fields here is a must: you really do not want someone to accidentally change your data. However, I think that mutable DTOs are evil and should be avoided; the only reason I see for their usage is compatibility with some API like Hibernate.

You also should hide fields when they comprise internal state you do not want anyone to access. This is the case with classes realizing some behavior (services, DAO etc). In this case you usually do not want even creating getters and setters.

So, in short, I would give the following advice: use immutable objects with public fields as your DTOs and make behavior classes which work on these DTO as closed as possible.